# How can I use regex in Python to extract location information from tweets about activism/protests?

Tags: python, regex, twitter, nlp

I'm working with a corpus I've scraped from Twitter activist communities in order to study the modern era of community organizing. I'm trying to run these data through re.findall in order to identify the tweets focused on location. I think that using the keyword "at" may be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Basically, if the entire tweet is (for example) "all who wish 2 join, meet at city hall 3pm", my code should print out something like "meet at city hall" for that line. Is this possible, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the utility of regex? I've only ever really used them for extracting email information previously, so I'm used to writing code like this:

```
match = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', line)
```

However, attempting to exchange the '@' in the code above for an 'at' doesn't yield any results.

I'm probably not even asking the right question here. Apologies for any confusion I cause and I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: First of all you must include the spaces before and after "at" in the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are just trying to match a sentence with the word "at" or "@"?

This is the regex I came up with:

```py
r'[\w\s]+(at|@)[\w\s]+\.?'
```

This will match any words before and after an "at" or "@".

For future reference: next time you are creating a regex, use https://regex101.com/. I find it helps a ton.